# Finding a basis for a certain vector space of periodic polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am having a little bit of trouble solving an homework question.

I found that $S={ p(x) \in R_4[x]} \big| p(x)=p(x-1) $ is a vector space.

Now I need to find some set, K that holds ${span(k)=S}$

My idea was to substitute: $ a+bx+cx^{2}+dx^{3}+ex^{4}=a+b(x-1)+c(x-1)^{2}+d(x-1)^{3}+e(x-1)^{4}$

But here I get something that seems a little bit weird, I'd like to look if I have any mistakes that I did not notice. and if I had mistakes, how to make my answer right.
I calculated the right side of the equation and I got to  :

$a+b(x-1)+c(x-1)^{2}+d(x-1)^{3}+e(x-1)^{4}=a+bx-b+cx^{2}-2cx+c+dx^{3}-3dx^{2}+3dx-d+ex^{4}-4ex^{3}+6ex^{2}-4ex+e=
(a-b+c-d+e)+(b-2c+3d-4e)x+(c-3d+6e)x^{2}+(d-4e)x^{3}+ex^{4}
 $

From here,
$
(a-b+c-d+e)+(b-2c+3d-4e)x+(c-3d+6e)x^{2}+(d-4e)x^{3}+ex^{4}=a+b(x-1)+c(x-1)^{2}+d(x-1)^{3}+e(x-1)^{4}\Rightarrow $

$(-b+c-d+e)+(-2c+3d-4e)x+(-3d+6e)x^{2}+(d-4e)x^{3}=0+0x+0x^{2}+0x^{3}+0x^{4}$

And the solution to this equation is only whan $a=b=c=d=e=0$.

I think that I am maybe not in the right direction.
Do you have any Idea how to find a set $K\Rightarrow span(K)=S$ ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points about your question.

1. After you made $a$ drop out of the equation (to obtain the equation that starts with $(-b+c-d+e)\cdots$), you nevertheless concluded that $a=0$ (among other things). This cannot be right, you can never get a conclusion about $a$ from an equation in which it is absent.
2. Supposing your conclusion $a=b=c=d=e=0$ would have been justified, then you would have arrived at the conclusion that your subspace contains only the polynomial $0$. This is wrong, but it is not anything contradictory in itself. In any case a subspace requires a number of basis vectors equal to the number of parameters that can be freely chosen. If you've got no such parameters, this would mean the basis has $0$ elements; it is the empty set ($K=\emptyset$).

In fact *all* constant polynomials (not just $0$) are solutions to your problem, so there is $1$ parameter ($a$) that can be freely chosen. So your subspace requires one basis vector (any nonzero constant polynomial will do for this purpose; the most obvious choice is the constant$~1$). In general, to pass from the description of a subspace in terms of parameters (obtained by solving a linear homogeneous system, as you did), select each free parameter in turn, make it$~1$ while making any other free parameter$~0$, and thus obtain one basis vector of the subspace for each free parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is correct, but the conclusion is not---the resulting system imposes no constraints on $a$, so the general solution is $p(x) = a$, and this is spanned by, e.g., the polynomial $p(x) = 1$.

Here's a more conceptual and less computational way to see this: Since any such p is by definition periodic with period 1, all of the values in its image $p(R)$ are achieved on the interval (for example) $[0,1]$. Now, p is a continuous, so $p(R)=p([0,1])$ is compact and hence bounded. But, the only bounded polynomials are constants, and all constant polynomials $p(x)=a$ satisfy the periodicity condition, so $S = \{p(x) = a : \text{$a$ constant}\}$.

Comment: Thank you.
I understand it intuitively, so it's not my problem.
If you can, I'd like you to explain what is wrong with my coclusion. As you can see I just used algebra, and it came to  $a=0$.

Comment: Like I said, your condition---the equation just before you conclude $a = b = c = d = e = 0$---imposes no constraints on $a$, as it doesn't even involve $a$. The rest of the conclusion is still correct, though, i.e., the other coefficients must all be zero. So, the general solution is $p(x) = a$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there exists a non-constant polynomial $p \in S$ of degree $d \geq 1$. I will get a contradiction, so that $S$ must contain only constant polynomials.

Write $p=\sum_{i=0}^d a_ix^i$ with $a_d \neq 0$ (because the degree is $d$). Then $p(x) = p(x-1)$ is equivalent to
$$\sum_{i=0}^d a_ix^i - \sum_{i=0}^d a_i(x-1)^i=0$$
but this implies that
$$da_d x^{d-1} + (\mbox{ other terms of degree at most $d-2$ }) =0$$
so $a_d=0$, and we get a contradiction.

Note that this argument works in any degree, and in any integral domain.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Buy my education in math isn't so high yet, and you did few transition which I did not understand, like what after you wrote "but this implies that..."
If is it possible to understnad what was my problem in my way, I'll thank you very much, cause as I mentioned, it's an H.W question and I'd not like to use a way I don't understand.

Comment: Just write down everything explicitely, as you did, and note that you can ignore the terms of lower degree.