# Finding a group that spans a vector space of Polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having problem finding a group that spans this vector space:

$S={ p(x) \in R_4[x]} \big| p(x)=p(x-1) $

My idea was to substitute: $ a+bx+cx^{2}+dx^{3}+ex^{4}=a+b(x-1)+c(x-1)^{2}+d(x-1)^{3}+e(x-1)^{4}$

But it led me nowhere.
what can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $R_4(x)$?

Comment: The set of polynomials, in this form $ a+bx+cx^{2}+dx^{3}+ex^{4}$.
@Travis

Comment: I didn't see that this was a duplicate...

Comment: Indeed --- Nir, what possessed you to post the same question twice?

Answer (score 0):

The set $S$ is the set of constant polynomials, so it is spanned by $1$.

Comment: How did you got to this solution? @Crosul

Comment: Any non-constant polynomial $p(x)$ has some complex roots, counted with multiplicity. Then the roots of $p(x-1)$ are the roots of $p(x)$ shifted by $1$ on the right (in the complex plane), so they cannot be the same set of roots. The only possibility for $p(x)=p(x-1)$ is that the polynomial has no roots, i.e. it is constant.

Another way to see this is to solve the equation you wrote and see that you must have $e=d=c=b=0$.

Comment: I did it, as you can see here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053465/finding-a-group-that-spans-a-vector-space
But, from some reason I got also $a=0$. 
What is the problem there? @Crostul

Comment: In the very last equation $a$ does not appear, so $a$ is "free", i.e. it can be anything.